# Convex Quadrilaterals in C

Tags: c, computational-geometry

Could anyone help me to finish my code? My program is supposed to count every different convex quadrilateral which may be formed from the given points. 
But my code count every convex quadrilateral, not just these, which are different.

Example:

```
input
5
0 0
6 0
0 6
6 6
5 3
output
3
```

But my program will printf 24 for this input, because it counts every convex quadrilateral more times. How can I edit my code to count quadrilateral just once?

EDIT: I have this code to store only different convex quadrilaterals, but my code is too slow, because it still try every option. Is there any other way to count convex quadrilaterals?
My edited code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int list[],int size) {
  // kontrola prohozeni
  int swapped = 1,temp;
  while (swapped) {
    swapped = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      // prohozeni
      if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
        temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = 1;
      }
    }
    size--;
  }
}

/**
struct for coordination
*/
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} POINT;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

} ZAZNAM;

/**
*   if point 'z' is on right from line 'xy', function return negative value;
*   if point 'z' is on left from line 'xy', function return positive value;
*   if point 'z' is on line 'xy', function return 0;
*/
int calculate_vector(POINT x, POINT y, POINT z)
{
    int ux = y.x - x.x;
    int uy = y.y - x.y;
    int vx = z.x - x.x;
    int vy = z.y - x.y;
    return ux*vy - uy*vx;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l,n;
    int res1,res2,res3,res4,num;
    res1 = res2 = res3 = res4 = num = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    POINT array[n];
    ZAZNAM zaz[120000];
    int cislo = 0;
    int nove;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d%d",&array[i].x, &array[i].y);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(j != i){
                for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    if(k != i && k != j){
                        for(l = 0; l < n; l++){
                            if(l != i && l != k && l != j){

                                                                                 //res1....res4 - position of point
                                res1 = calculate_vector(array[i],array[j],array[k]);   //position of *THIRD* POINT relative to line from the *FIRST* point to the *SECOND* point
                                res2 = calculate_vector(array[j],array[k],array[l]);   //position of *FOURTH* POINT relative to line from the *SECOND* point to the *THIRD* point
                                res3 = calculate_vector(array[l],array[k],array[i]);   //position of *FIRST* POINT relative to line from the *THIRD* point to the *FOURTH* point
                                res4 = calculate_vector(array[i],array[l],array[j]);   //position of *SECOND* POINT relative to line from the *FOURTH* point to the *FIRST* point
                                if((res1 > 0 && res2 > 0 && res3 > 0 && res4 > 0)||(res1 < 0 && res2 < 0 && res3 < 0 && res4 < 0)){ //if all points are from each other on right or on left, the quadrilateral is convex.
                                    int sort[4];
                                    sort[0] = i;
                                    sort[1] = j;
                                    sort[2] = k;
                                    sort[3] = l;
                                    bubbleSort(sort,3);
                                    nove = 1;
                                    for(int p = 0; p < cislo; p++){
                                        if(sort[0] == zaz[p].a && sort[1] == zaz[p].b && sort[2] == zaz[p].c && sort[3] == zaz[p].d){
                                            nove = 0;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if(nove){
                                       zaz[cislo].a = sort[0];
                                       zaz[cislo].b = sort[1];
                                       zaz[cislo].c = sort[2];
                                       zaz[cislo++].d = sort[3];
                                       num++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mark out quads as you count them.

Comment: What exactly causes your code to continue after its been considered a convex quadrilateral? This part `if((res1 > 0 && res2 > 0 && res3 > 0 && res4 > 0)||(res1 < 0 && res2 < 0 && res3 < 0 && res4 < 0)){  num++; }` allows your program to continue its computation - should you stop the program here once you have determined one point is convex?

Comment: This part only try if these 4 points can form a convex quadrilateral. But my problem is that my program tries  every possible option(in loops), so many  quadrilateral are counted more times, but in mixed order(like 0 2 3 1 is same as 0 1 2 3, but it is counted 2 times).

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one else is answering this, so I'll take a crack at it.  Not sure how your code does this, as it is lacking some clarity at least for me.

1. Create a QUAD struct made up of 4 POINTs.

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
       POINT pt1;
       POINT pt2;
       POINT pt3;
       POINT pt4;
   }QUAD;
   ```
2. Create an array of QUAD objects to store the quads you want to keep.

   ```
   QUAD Quads[MAX_QUADS]
   ```

or if you calculate the total number of possible quads based on the number of inputs using combination formula(12 take 4)

```
QUAD *Quads;
Quads = (QUAD*)malloc(nCombos * sizeof(QUAD));
```

Now, for any combination of 4 points there is only ever going to be 1 "real" quad that is formed.  Some of the remainder are complex(and thus not convex) and the rest are repeats linearly shifted, inverted, or both.  So start by forming a quad(in whichever for loops does that) and storing it in a QUAD structure, then calculate all the angles using vector math forming vectors from adjacent member Points(12 & 23 make up one set of vectors for instance, 23 & 34 make up the next etc).

Now check the angles.  If all are < 90 you have a complex quad so scratch and go to the next combination.  If any of the angles are > 180 it is a real convex quad so check your index(for the array of QUADs from earlier) to see if you have any other quads already stored, if you do iterate through each one comparing it with the current one with the following function:

```
bool bCompareQuads(QUAD qd1, QUAD qd2)    
{
    if(qd1.pt1 == qd2.pt1)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt1 == qd2.pt2)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt1 == qd2.pt3)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt1 == qd2.pt4)
        counter++;

    if(qd1.pt2 == qd2.pt1)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt2 == qd2.pt2)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt2 == qd2.pt3)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt2 == qd2.pt4)
        counter++;

    if(qd1.pt3 == qd2.pt1)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt3 == qd2.pt2)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt3 == qd2.pt3)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt3 == qd2.pt4)
        counter++;

    if(qd1.pt4 == qd2.pt1)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt4 == qd2.pt2)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt4 == qd2.pt3)
        counter++;
    if(qd1.pt4 == qd2.pt4)
        counter++;

    if(counter > 3)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

    return false;//shouldn't happen, but just in case
}
```

If it comes back true just break out without storing it, but if it doesn't store the new quad in the array.  At the end you simply print out all the QUADS that have been stored in your array.